# how to show tick image when the image was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have images when i select the images one by one while selecting i highlight the image with `border:2px solid #b404ae;` but i want to put the tick image in the bottom of images while images is selected but it unsuccessful can any one tell me how to do that (i.e. its not showing the image its only showing the bored color)

css:

```
 .highlighted {
             border:2px solid #b404ae;
             background-image: url(image/tick.png);

           }
```

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


           var ImageSelector = function() {
              var imgs = null;
              var selImg = null;

              return {
                 addImages: function(container) {
                    imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
                    for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
                       var img = imgs[i];
                       img.className = "normal";
                       img.onclick = function()  {
                          if(selImg)   {
                             selImg.className = "normal";
                          }
                          this.className = "highlighted";
                          selImg = this;
                       };
                    }
                 }
              };
           }();

          </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

              var div = document.getElementById("textbox");
              ImageSelector.addImages(div);

          </script>
```

Comment: can you share fiddle for y our code

Answer (score 4):

you can add a span tag next to the image and have that positioned over the image. Also, have the html code (`&#10004;`) for tick mark within the span. I have written a small modification of your function.

JSFiddle Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/hz8q9z17/3/

```js
var ImageSelector = function() {
  var imgs = null;
  var selImg = null;
  return {
    addImages: function(container) {
      imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
      for (var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var img = imgs[i];
        img.className = "normal";
        img.nextSibling.className = "normal";
        img.onclick = function() {
          if (selImg) {
            selImg.className = "normal";
            selImg.nextSibling.className = "normal";
          }
          this.className = "highlighted";
          this.nextSibling.className = "highlighted";
          selImg = this;
        };
      }
    }
  };
}();
var div = document.getElementById("textbox");
ImageSelector.addImages(div);
```

```css
.highlighted {
    border:2px solid #b404ae;
    background-image: url(image/tick.png);
}
#textbox span {
    bottom: 4px;
    color: #0f0;
    left: -15px;
    position: relative;
    display:none;
    border:none;
}
#textbox span.highlighted {
    display:inline;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
    <img src="http://www.flags.net/images/smallflags/CHIN0001.GIF" /><span class="tickmark">&#10004;</span><br />
  <img src="http://www.flags.net/images/smallflags/UNST0001.GIF" /><span class="tickmark">&#10004;</span><br />
  <img src="http://www.flags.net/images/smallflags/INDA0001.GIF" /><span class="tickmark">&#10004;</span><br />
  <img src="http://www.flags.net/images/smallflags/UNKG0001.GIF" /><span class="tickmark">&#10004;</span><br />
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
           var ImageSelector = function() {
              var imgs = null;
              var selImg = null;
              return {
                 addImages: function(container) {

                    imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
                    for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
                       var img = imgs[i];

                       img.className = "normal";
                       img.onclick = function()  {
                          if(selImg)   {
                             selImg.className = "normal";
                            selImg = null;
                           }
                            this.className = "highlighted";
                            selImg = this;
                        

                         
                          
                       };
                    }
                 }
              };
           }();

              var div = document.getElementById("textbox");
              ImageSelector.addImages(div);
```

```css
.highlighted {
  border: 2px solid #b404ae;
}

img {
 height: 40px;
  width: 122px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="textbox">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```